# How to create Cygwin compatible library files from native Windows .dll and/or .lib files

Tags: dll, cygwin, posix, .a, .lib

I have downloaded both a .dll and a .lib file compatible for 32-bit Windows from [libspotify](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/). The project I am working on requires me to use other libraries that does not work on Windows, but compile and work using Cygwin. I therefore need a way to get the .dll and/or .lib file "converted" into a compatible Cygwin format. Is that possible?

The .dll file does not contain symbols, so the suggested method described in the bottom of the [Cygwin doc](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/dll.html) did not work.

The other libraries that I have, generated the following files:

```
/usr/local/lib/{libname.la, libname.dll.a and sometimes libname.a}
/usr/local/bin/cyglibname.dll
```

Where libname is the name of the library correctly compiled and installed. How do I get these files from the native 32-bit Windows .dll and .lib files?

Update:

I tried to include the full path to the .dll file instead of using -l and -L as I am used to linking libraries, and I got the following message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: i386 architecture of input file `/usr/local/test/libspotify.dll' is 
incompatible with i386:x86-64 output
```

It seems like the problem is the 32-bit vs 64-bit. Anyone know how to fix that?

Another update:

It worked by adding -m32 to CFLAGS and LDFLAGS. I now got a different error that I believe is irrelevant for the original question.

Answer (score 0):

> *It seems like the problem is the 32-bit vs 64-bit. Anyone know how to fix that?*

Yes; use 32 bit Cygwin for a project that depends on third party DLL's only available in 32 bit form. Do not use 64 bit Cygwin.

Cygwin and Cygwin-64 can be installed side by side, by the way. (And it's possible to share the same home folder between them, so you don't have to duplicate your `.bashrc` and whatnot.)

This is not a Cygwin problem. If you build a 64 bit executable with, say, Microsoft Visual Studio, it also will not load the 32 bit `libspotify` DLL.